# Compare two files based on first column only and remove duplicate row from 2nd file in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, awk, compare

I will ask my question with an example. I have 2 files:

File # 1

```
002948998 752986QAK NTR974VTS 0000000    
102948932 752986QSC NTR974VTS 0000000    
102948933 752986QSC NTR974VTS 0000000
```

File #2

```
002901998 752986KFK NTR974MTS 0990000
002948998 752986QAQ NTR974VTS 0000000
002901998 752986KFK NTR974MTJ 0990000
```

Desired output :

```
002948998 752986QAK NTR974VTS 0000000    
102948932 752986QSC NTR974VTS 0000000    
102948933 752986QSC NTR974VTS 0000000    
002901998 752986KFK NTR974MTS 0990000
```

Note: there is no gap (enter) between the rows.

I'd like to compare file 1 and file 2 using their first columns and remove the entire row from file 2 if they match in file 1. I'd also like to save the results to a 1st file or a new file, file #3 which contains all the entries from file 1 and file 2 ( without the duplicates from file 2). Please advise a good resolution in shell script.

currently i am using :

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1];print;next} !($1 in a)' file1 file2 > file3
```

but it is not comparing based on only 1st column. instead it is comparing the whole row.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a famous-ish awk idiom: print a line only when the first field is seen for the first time:

```
awk '!seen[$1]++' file1 file2 > file3
```

```
002948998 752986QAK NTR974VTS 0000000    
102948932 752986QSC NTR974VTS 0000000    
102948933 752986QSC NTR974VTS 0000000
002901998 752986KFK NTR974MTS 0990000
```

This relies on:

- awk considering unset array elements as zero
- post-increment returning the variable's current value
- default action for "true" condition is to print the line

---

Preserving all lines in first file, while removing dups in second file

```
awk '!seen[$1]++ || NR==FNR' file1 file2 > file3
```

Comment: Thank you. where will be the output saved ? there is no file 3 in your code ?

Comment: thanks glenn. This code removes the duplicates from file 1 as well. i don't want to change the contents of file 1. i am creating a new file taking inputs from file 2 and checking if 1st column entry matches with any entry of 1st column of file 1. if no then they get added to the file 3 along with origianl content of file 1.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
cp file1 file3;
grep -Fv "$(cut -f 1 -d ' ' < file1)" file2 >> file3
```

Comment: Could you please explain the code a bit :) thank you . i will try this

Comment: Copy file 1 into file 3.  Then take the first column of file1 (cut -f 1 -d ' ') and use it as a literal pattern to match negatively the lines in file2, and append that output into file3

Comment: You could also try "sort" with a key, and "unique".  The man page for sort should help you a little, but it will only work if you have fixed columns (all the same size).  From your sample data: sort -k1,9 -u file1 file2, but it will also reorder, which I am not sure you want to do.